# Parse JSON packet input in java

Tags: java, json, sockets

I have a TCP socket connected to a server communicating via JSON. Since it's a stream the packets often merge into one larger through the inputstream, and I've been trying to parse it correctly but haven't found a successful way to read the input.

The input looks something like this

```
 +@$3{"data1":"datahere","moredata":25}2*${"data1":"differentdata","otherdata":001}
```

This I have parsed to be

```
{"data1":"datahere","moredata":25}{"data1":"differentdata","otherdata":001}
```

Using a reader only returns the first json object when it is set to lenient, otherwise it throws an exception. The JSON comes from a socket, and is a result of packet merging. What can be done in a JSON library to parse these separately?

Comment: Neither the input or expected output appear to be valid JSON.  The input has garbage symbols and the output would need some commas and brackets to be a JSON array.

Comment: Are there any rules for what the junk in the input would look like, such that we might devise a way to remove it?

Comment: The server sends a JSON with data before, which I truncate since they aren't useful(they do not contain packet length). I have parsed so that the useless data is removed, however I fail to parse it into two separate JSON(the second code is what I managed to get). It is supposed to be two separate packets which is easy to manage, however the TCP input stream merges them into one so I have to separate them in some way, hence the "garbage" formatting.

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  If you want to use a regex to remove the junk formatting, we would need to have some patterns for how it might be appearing.

Comment: Ah, pardon me, I must have been unclear. I have successfully removed the junk w/o regex, I just failed to parse the final JSON since there are multiple JSON's in one line as indicated by the second code; when attempting to read it truncates the second one. I fail to succeed in parsing them separately, that was the issue at hand; sorry if I failed to bring forth my problem.